# Сделать обновление пароля в базе данных

Tags: php, пароль, база-данных

Хочу сделать обновление пароля в базе данных. И никак не получается уже все перепробовал. Не понимаю, что не так(
Вот форма смены пароля

```
<input type="password" placeholder="Old password" name="lastpass" value="">
<input type="password" placeholder="New password" name="newpass" value="" >
<input type="password" placeholder="Repeat new password" name="newpassw" value="" >
<input type="submit" class="btn_savechange" value="Save" name="savech" />
```

Вот код смены пароля, который не работает

```
<?php

      if(isset($_POST['savech']))
      {
       $lastpass = $_POST['lastpass'];
       $newpass = $_POST['newpass'];
       $newpassw = $_POST['newpassw'];
          if ($newpassw == $newpass)
          {
      $qery = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE login = 'login'") or die(mysql_error());

                 if (mysql_num_rows($qery) == 1) {
       $updated = "UPDATE users SET password = '$newpass' WHERE login = 'login'";
       if(mysql_num_rows($update) > 0)
       {
               echo "Good";
       }
       else {
               echo "mistake";
       }
                         }
                         else {
                                 echo "Oshibka";
                         }
          }
            }

?>
```

Пользователь авторизуется и данные записаны в сессиях. Может через них надо как то вытаскивать. Помогите код исправить.

Comment: @Amir90, Чтобы отформатировать код, выделите его мышью и нажмите на кнопку {} редактора.

Comment: да нет они одинаковые $update, $updated. это я скопировал потмо затетил исправил) а вы смысле функции умерли а что использовать???

Comment: умерли и использовать теперь (уже давно) нужно PDO - почему, как и зачем объясняют тут: [Почему стоит пользоваться PDO для работы с базой данных](http://habrahabr.ru/post/137664/)

Comment: Надеюсь это тестовый код? Сохранять пароли можно только в хэшированном виде.

Answer (score 2):

Все точно перепробовали?:) А посмотреть в код?

```
$updated = "UPDATE users SET password = '$newpass' WHERE login = 'login'";
       if(mysql_num_rows($update)
```

Название переменных разные - $update, $updated

mysql_ функции уже умерли, их не используют.

Думаю скоро как хэшкод будет побольше, такие вопросы будут блокироваться.

Answer (score 1):

Для update нужно вызывать [mysql_query](https://www.php.net/manual/ru/function.mysql-query.php), а не [mysql_num_rows](https://www.php.net/mysql_num_rows).

Comment: о) спасибо заработало)))))))))))))))